# how to get the data from stored proc n show on the dropdownbox in c# .net client side?

Tags: c#, .net

How can I get the data from stored proc n show on the dropdownbox in c# .net client side? I have to tried the follwoing code but this is not working for me .. :( can anyone tell me what is going wrong here?

```
   <div id="test-area">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownEventType"  runat="server" CssClass="dropDownEventType" DataSourceID="spdropDownEventType">
                        <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:AccessDataSource 
                        ConnectionString="<%= ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>"
                        SelectCommand="app_Event_Type_Select" 
                        SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"  
                        ID="spdropDownEventType" 
                        runat="server"></asp:AccessDataSource>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>
```

Comment: One thing you are missing is the DataTextField and DataValueField so the dropdown knows what fields to use for text and value. Are you sure the stored procedure is returning data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Try to add DataTextField and DataValueField to the DropDownList.
2. Delete the attribute `ConnectionString`, and set the `DataFile` preporty codebehind. You can not use `<%= %>` in a server-side control attribute, it will cause parse error

aspx

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownEventType"  runat="server" CssClass="dropDownEventType" DataSourceID="spdropDownEventType" 
                DataTextField="yourEventName" 
                DataValueField="yourEventValue">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:AccessDataSource 
                SelectCommand="app_Event_Type_Select" 
                SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"  
                ID="spdropDownEventType" 
                runat="server"></asp:AccessDataSource>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    spdropDownEventType.DataFile = "your access db file path";
}
```

Comment: Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this post: http://forums.asp.net/t/1486795.aspx/1

On codebehind, you need something like this:

```
DropDownEventType.DataTextField="TextFieldColumnName"
DropDownEventType.DataValueField="ValueFieldColumnName"
DropDownEventType.DataBind()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div id="test-area">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownEventType"  runat="server" CssClass="dropDownEventType" DataSourceID="spdropDownEventType">
                    DataTextField="Name" 
                    DataValueField="EventTypeID">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:AccessDataSource 
                    ConnectionString="<%= ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>"
                    SelectCommand="app_Event_Type_Select" 
                    SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"  
                    ID="spdropDownEventType" 
                    runat="server"></asp:AccessDataSource>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</div>
```

OR

Bind Drop down in code behind

```
DropDownEventType.DataSource = datable value;   
DropDownEventType.DataTextField="Name";
DropDownEventType.DataValueField="EventTypeID";
DropDownEventType.DataBind();
```